# Authentication Refresh Token

Tags: reactjs, axios, redux-thunk

Building a login form using Reactjs, redux, axios and redux-thunk. I have two tokens - one named `access token` and `refresh token`.

When the user is authenticated, store the `access token` which should last for 12 hours. The `refresh token` is also provided and will last 30 days.

Once the `access token` has expired need to check the timestamp (date) if `access token` is expired.

How can I update the `access token` once expired? Token data looks like this so I have a timestamp to check against:

```
{
  "access_token": "toolongtoinclude",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "refresh_token": "toolongtoinclude",
  "expires_in": 43199,
  "scope": "read write",
  "roles": [
    "USER"
  ],
  "profile_id": "b4d1e37d-7d05-4eb3-98de-0580d3074a0d",
  "jti": "e975db65-e3b7-4034-a6e4-9a3023c3d175"
}
```

Here are my actions to save, get and update tokens from storage. I'm just unsure on how to refresh the token.

```
export function submitLoginUser(values, dispatch) {
    dispatch({type: constants.LOADING_PAGE, payload: { common: true }})
    return axios.post(Config.API_URL + '/oauth/token', {
            username: values.email,
            password: values.password,
            scope: Config.WEBSERVICES_SCOPE,
            grant_type: Config.WEBSERVICES_GRANT_TYPE_PASSWORD
        },
        {
            transformRequest: function (data) {
                var str = [];
                for (var p in data) {
                    str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[p]));
                }

                return str.join('&');
            },
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Basic ' + window.btoa(Config.WEBSERVICES_AUTH),
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        })
        .then(response => {
            const {access_token, refresh_token} = response.data;
            dispatch({type: constants.LOADING_PAGE, payload: { common: false }})
            dispatch({
                type: constants.LOGIN_SUCCESS,
                payload: {
                    access_token: access_token,
                    refresh_token: refresh_token
                }
            });
            saveTokens(response)
            browserHistory.push('/questions');
            refreshToken(response);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            dispatch({type: constants.LOADING_PAGE, payload: { common: false }})
            //401 Error catch
            if(error.response.status === 401) {
              throw new SubmissionError({username: 'User is not authenticated', _error: message.LOGIN.loginUnAuth})
            }
            //Submission Error
            throw new SubmissionError({username: 'User does not exist', _error: message.LOGIN.loginFailed})
        })
}

/**
 * Save tokens in local storage and automatically add token within request
 * @param params
 */
export function saveTokens(params) {
    const {access_token, refresh_token} = params.data;
    localStorage.setItem('access_token', access_token);
    if (refresh_token) {
        localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', refresh_token);
    }
    //todo fix this later
    getinstanceAxios().defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `bearer ${access_token}`
}

/**
 *
 */
export function getTokens() {
    let accessToken = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
    return accessToken
}

/**
 * update the get requests
 */
export function updateTokenFromStorage() {
    const tokenLocalStorage = getTokens();
    getinstanceAxios().defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `bearer ${tokenLocalStorage}`;
}

/**
 * Refresh user access token
 */
export function refreshToken(dispatch) {
    //check timestamp
    //check access expired - 401

    //request new token, pass refresh token
    //store both new access and refresh tokens

}
```

Comment: why don't create a interceptor to all your requests. This interceptor is going to check if your token is still valid or not, you know? If not, send to a new route or shows up some message.

Comment: Thank you for this Valter - I will look into interceptors for axios.

Answer (score 0):

check this out:

`https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#interceptors`

I think this can help you. You intercept your request and make your validations.

EDIT

Here is the code I've tried to use in my store to test, not getting any log back

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import { devTools, persistState } from 'redux-devtools'
import axios from 'axios'
import Middleware from '../middleware'
import Reducer from '../reducers/reducer'
import DevTools from '../containers/DevTools'

let finalCreateStore

if (__DEVELOPMENT__ && __DEVTOOLS__) {

  finalCreateStore = compose(
   applyMiddleware.apply(this, Middleware),
   // Provides support for DevTools:
      DevTools.instrument(),
   // Optional. Lets you write ?debug_session=<key> in address bar to persist debug sessions
   persistState(getDebugSessionKey())
 )(createStore)
} else {
  finalCreateStore = compose(
   applyMiddleware.apply(this, Middleware)
 )(createStore)
}

function getDebugSessionKey() {
  // You can write custom logic here!
  // By default we try to read the key from ?debug_session=<key> in the address bar
  const matches = window.location.href.match(/[?&]debug_session=([^&]+)\b/)
  return (matches && matches.length > 0)? matches[1] : null
}

axios.interceptors.response.use((err) => {
    if (err.status === 401) {
        console.log('ACCESS TOKEN EXPIRED!');
    }
});


export const store = finalCreateStore(Reducer)
```

Comment: Thanks for this valter - I'm just confused as to where the interceptors function is going to be called?

Comment: Have you tried to use to see if solves your problem? Try to add at your index.js or the place you create your Root component, store, etc. Try there and see if it works. We can think later in a better place although I think this is a good place.

Comment: This is half the problem I'm unsure how to use this, not used it before - very new to this sorry. I'm looking at my store index.js file and wondering what I can write to test this?

Comment: Valter - please see edit to your answer with updated code from my store.

Comment: I saw. Is this working? Is the console.log been called on every request?

Comment: Unfortunately not - i'm unsure why

Comment: try to add the axios interceptor code right before some request just to check if it's calling the console. After that we can try to find another place to put it.